# Upload image on server from mobile application

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am working on a mobile application on .net. This is a windows mobile application. I am facing a problem in this application that I wanna upload an image/file to given url/server. Many upload classes is not using like Webclient, WebRequest, WebResponse. I used HttpWebRequest, That is not connecting with server. Please anyone can help me on how to upload the images on given url in windows mobile 6 in .net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: *Exact* dupe (to the letter) of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897120/upload-images-in-windows-mobile-6-in-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey take a look at this code for uploading at Image Shack:

You can modify it to use with other web site by just using Fiddler to change the web requests

```
public class Uploader
    {

        public string UploadFileToImageShack(object oFileName)
        {
            try
            {
                string fileName = oFileName as string;
                string contentType = null;
                CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
                NameValueCollection col = new NameValueCollection();
                col["MAX_FILE_SIZE"] = "3145728";
                col["refer"] = "";
                col["brand"] = "";
                col["optimage"] = "1";
                col["rembar"] = "1";
                col["submit"] = "host it!";
                List<string> l = new List<string>();
                switch (fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 3, 3))
                {
                    case "jpg":
                        contentType = "image/jpeg";
                        break;
                    case "peg":
                        contentType = "image/jpeg";
                        break;
                    case "gif":
                        contentType = "image/gif";
                        break;
                    case "png":
                        contentType = "image/png";
                        break;
                    case "bmp":
                        contentType = "image/bmp";
                        break;
                    case "tif":
                        contentType = "image/tiff";
                        break;
                    case "iff":
                        contentType = "image/tiff";
                        break;
                    default:
                        contentType = "image/unknown";
                        break;
                }

                string resp;
                col["optsize"] = "resample";
                resp = UploadFileEx(fileName,
                                               "http://www.imageshack.us/index.php",
                                               "fileupload",
                                               contentType,
                                               col,
                                               cookie);
                return resp;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }



        public static string UploadFileEx(string uploadfile, string url,
           string fileFormName, string contenttype, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection querystring,
           CookieContainer cookies)
        {
            if ((fileFormName == null) ||
                (fileFormName.Length == 0))
            {
                fileFormName = "file";
            }

            if ((contenttype == null) ||
                (contenttype.Length == 0))
            {
                contenttype = "application/octet-stream";
            }


            string postdata;
            postdata = "?";
            if (querystring != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in querystring.Keys)
                {
                    postdata += key + "=" + querystring.Get(key) + "&";
                }
            }
            Uri uri = new Uri(url + postdata);


            string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            webrequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
            webrequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            webrequest.Method = "POST";


            // Build up the post message header
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("--");
            sb.Append(boundary);
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"");
            sb.Append(fileFormName);
            sb.Append("\"; filename=\"");
            sb.Append(Path.GetFileName(uploadfile));
            sb.Append("\"");
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            sb.Append("Content-Type: ");
            sb.Append(contenttype);
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            sb.Append("\r\n");

            string postHeader = sb.ToString();
            byte[] postHeaderBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postHeader);

            // Build the trailing boundary string as a byte array
            // ensuring the boundary appears on a line by itself
            byte[] boundaryBytes =
                   Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(uploadfile,
                                        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            long length = postHeaderBytes.Length + fileStream.Length +
                                                   boundaryBytes.Length;
            webrequest.ContentLength = length;

            Stream requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();

            // Write out our post header
            requestStream.Write(postHeaderBytes, 0, postHeaderBytes.Length);

            // Write out the file contents
            byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096,
                                     (int)fileStream.Length))];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            // Write out the trailing boundary
            requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
            WebResponse responce = webrequest.GetResponse();
            Stream s = responce.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);

            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        } 


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [example code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uploadfileex.aspx) on CodeProject that reimplements `WebClient.UploadFile` "with more" using just `HttpwebRequest` and friends, which at first glance looks like it uses features that are available in the Compact Framework. You could check the code works with the full framework on a PC and use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check what goes over the wire., before then compiling for the Compact Framework.

Comment: I am really sorry but as you said, I checked that and found this solution is not for windows mobile application. This is not running.

Comment: What's stopping that from compiling against the Compact Framework? Whilst I only took a cursory glance, I couldn't see anything that isn't in the Compact Framework...